# Problem in pushing React app - Create React App template is pushing instead of my app

Tags: git, github

I am pushing my React app to GitHub to host it on GitHub Pages. But when I push it to GitHub, the create-react-app template is getting pushed rather than my app. I am following the steps below:

1. Creating a new repository.
2. Now I open my code in VS Code and open the terminal and run following commands:

   ```
   git remote add origin https://github.com/UserName/ProjectName.git
   git branch -M main
   git push -u origin main
   ```
3. Refresh the GitHub repository.

After these steps only some template is getting pushed instead of my app. What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://blog.logrocket.com/deploying-react-apps-github-pages/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the files to staging and commit them before pushing.

```
git add files you want to add
git commit -m "commit message"
git push -u origin main
```

for example pushing all my local changes

```
git add .
git commit -m "fix some issue"
git push -u origin main
```